# Leap year with boolean

Tags: python, boolean, syntax-error

I have a leap year calculator in Python via import Calendar + calendar.isleap
I do a print statement via a Boolean. However, my Boolean is always giving me a syntax error.
The error is in `if b == False`. Code below.

```
import calendar 

def main():

    try:
        a = int(input("Which year should I process? ").replace(',','.'))
        b = calendar.isleap(a)
        if b == False
                print(a,"is not a leap year")
            else:
                print(a,"is a leap year")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input!"
        main()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a colon:

```
if b == False:
#            ^
```

And your indentation is off:

```
if b == False
    print(a,"is geen schrikkeljaar")
else:   # Indentation is wonky here.  Check that you're not mixing tabs and spaces...
    print(a,"is een schrikkeljaar")
```

Note that it is very weird to see `if be == False` in code.  Normally you'd write:

```
if not b:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the indentation too. I now however get a syntax error on main() at the end of the code..

Comment: @Menubalk -- That's because you're missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Missing ')'!